# Unable to close all toggled divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create two divs(left and right) .If an link is clicked on left it should open the data in the right div and in the right div there are multiple questions. Each question is clickable and it shows answers on click. 
I have implemented this but when a question opens the previous question won't close and I want it to close.I have used toggle which closes the same link.
my code is as follows

```
$('.targetDiv').hide();
    $('.show').click(function () {
        $('.targetDiv').hide();
        $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle();
    });
$('.innerdiv').hide();
$('.answer').click(function(){
   $('.innerdiv').hide(); 
 $('#innerdiv' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle();   
});
```

```html
<html>
    <div style="width: 30%; float:left">
    <div class="buttons">
     <ul>
      <li><a  class="show" target="1">Placing an Order</a></li>
      <li><a  class="show" target="2">blah.com Returns & Cancellations FAQs</a></li>
      <li><a  class="show" target="3">Brands & Stock</a></li>
      <li><a  class="show" target="4">Shipping & Delivery</a></li>
      <li><a  class="show" target="5">Payment</a></li>
      <li><a  class="show" target="6">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a  class="show" target="7">Value Added Tax (VAT)</a></li>
      <li><a  class="show" target="8">Privacy & Security</a></li>
      <li><a  class="show" target="9">About the Company</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="width: 70%; float:right">
   <div id="div1" class="targetDiv">
    <ul>
    <li><a class="answer" target="1">I need personal assistance with my order. Who can I contact?</a><div id="innerdiv1" class="innerdiv" >Our customer service centre is happy to assist you with your order on +91 124 6733300 (10 AM - 7 PM)</div>
    </li>
    <li><a class="answer" target="2" >How do I start a new account?</a><div id="innerdiv2" class="innerdiv">blah blah </div></li>
    <li><a class="answer" target="3">I am having problems ordering through your website. What can I do?</a> <div id="innerdiv3" class="innerdiv"> hahahahah </div></li>
    <li><a class="answer" target="4" >I need personal assistance with my order. Who can I contact?</a> <div id="innerdiv4" class="innerdiv"> b;la ablahhap </div></li>
    <li><a class="answer" target="5" >How do I start a new account?</a><div id="innerdiv5" class="innerdiv">blah blah </div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot to paste your code

Comment: Paste your code here.

Comment: ..or create a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: jsfiddle? jsbin? whatever you have tried till now?

Comment: Sorry Please see if you can help me now

Comment: Please give a useful outline of the problem in the title.

Comment: it is called Master-Details

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sKJA3/0) If anyone wants to give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

Try this one : 
You have first to iterate through all the `li` items under the `ul` and 'close' them

```
$('.answer').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('ul').find('li').find('.innerdiv').hide(); 
     $('#innerdiv' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle();   
});
```